# anonymous function calls within anonymous Function definitions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function

I would love to know why this code is not working. if anyone has any information on what is causing matlab to find so many errors, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
m = 1;
c = 1.5;
fun =@(x, epsilon) 1 .* (1 - (1 - cos(x))/(2.*epsilon)).^c .* cos(m.*x);
a = @(ep) acos(1-(2*ep));

lm =@(e) 1/(2.*pi) .* integral(@(x)fun(x, e), -1.*a(e), a(e));
fprintf('ball bearing at 0.6 is %4.4f', lm(0.6));
```

the function that I am trying to replicate is `() =1/2∫[1 − (1 − cos())/2]^ cos()dx`

There should be no need for the dot modifier on the multiplication to my knowledge, however Matlab was complaining that this required element-wise operations even though there are no matrices involved.

Comment: This ran for me as is using 2017b, giving the output `ball bearing at 0.6 is 0.2416`.

Comment: “So many errors”. Please copy-paste the errors so we can see them too. It helps in finding out what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`integral`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) the function to be integrated must be vectorized:

> For scalar-valued problems, the function `y = fun(x)` must accept a vector argument, `x`, and return a vector result, `y`. This generally means that fun must use array operators instead of matrix operators. For example, use `.*` (*times*) rather than `*` (*mtimes*).